# Do Facebook Analytics custom events not work when logged in a static class?

Tags: java, android, facebook-analytics

I am trying to log custom events in the Android app using Facebook analytics. The custom events are working correctly whenever I log them in MainActivity and other Activities in my app, but are not getting logged at all when I log them inside Fragments and static methods.

I initialize the Facebook SDK and AppEventsLogger in my Application class like his:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
```

And I track events in my app like this:

```
TrackingService.logEvent(getActivity(), "Public.Clicked");
```

And here is the logEvent method that I defined in my TrackingService:

```
static public void logEvent(Activity activity, String event) {
    AppEventsLogger logger = AppEventsLogger.newLogger(activity);
    logger.logEvent(event);
}
```

When I call logEvent in a method in my MainActivity, the event shows up in my Facebook Analytics dashboard:

```
TrackingService.logEvent(MainActivity.this, "SearchTestA");
```

When I call logEvent in a method in one of my Fragments that is contained within MainActivity, the event does not show up in my dashboard:

```
TrackingService.logEvent(getActivity(), "Public.Clicked");
```

I have confirmed that getActivity() above returns an instance of MainActivity. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out you can't have periods in your event names. Underscores and spaces are allowed, though.